# Limit the scale of a pick whipped object

Tags: after-effects, audio, after-effects-expressions

I want to make a speaker graphic 'wobble' to different frequencies..
Here's what I've done so far

I made a speaker graphic in a comp
And I parented the scale to a null in the main comp

[image]

And I *isolated* the kick drum with a combo of a band pass filter and a bass-treble.
Then I converted that audio into keyframes and pick whipped that null with that speaker's scale parented to it.

[image]

So here's where I'm stuck at:
I want to **limit** the speaker's scale within some values. Like the speaker should not exceed 75.8% and 76% of scale.

So what I tried so far is something like this ↓
temp = thisComp.layer("Audio Amplitude").effect("Both Channels")("Slider");
[temp, temp]  +[Math.min(73.8-2), Math.min(73.8-2)] [Math.max(23), Math.max(23)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a linear map as an Expression.
So the example below would take any value between 0-100 and map it between -100 to 100.

```
input = effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
inputLow = 0;
inputHigh = 100;
outputLow = -100;
outputHigh = 100;

linear(input,inputLow,inputHigh,outputLow,outputHigh)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new to expressions, can you please show me how I put that into my rest of the expression?

Comment: Edit - Thanks man, after you gave me a primer, I was able to find it on Google...